# mysql table performance upgrade (indexes

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to find a way to improve performance for my mysql table containing ip ranges (it's gonna have up to 500 SELECT queries per second (!) in peak hours so I am little worried).

I have a table of this structure:

```
id  smallint(5) Auto Increment   
ip_start    char(16)     
ip_end  char(16)
```

Coding is `utf8_general_ci`(on whole table and each columns except id), table is type of MyISAM (only SELECT queries, no insert/delete needed here). Indexes for this table are `PRIMARY id`.

At this momen table has almost 2000 rows. All of them contains ranges for ip. 
For example:

```
ip_start 128.6.230.0
ip_end 128.6.238.255
```

When user comes to a website I am checking if his ip is in some of those ranges in my table. I use this query (dibi sql library):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM ip_ranges
 WHERE %s", $user_ip, " BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end
```

If result of query is not zero then the ip of the user is in one of those ranges in table - which is all i need it to do.

I was thinking maybe about putting some indexes to that table? But i am not quite sure how it works and if it's such a good idea (since there is maybe nothing to really index, right? most of those ip ranges are different).

I also had varchar type on those ip_start and ip_end columns but i switched it to just char (guess its faster?).

Anyone any ideas about how to improve this table/queries even further?

Comment: it'd help, but you're comparing STRINGS... that will end badly since ips aren't really strings... e.g. `10.0.0.0, 101.0.0.0, 9.9.9.9` are in ascending string order, but they're definitely not in "numerical" order...

Comment: You could use clustered index on ip_start, ip_end, but as Marc said it is not good idea to use strings here. You could try ip2int algorithm and use integer comparision instead

Comment: There are the MySQL INET_ATON() AND INET_NTOA() functions as well. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

Comment: Yes, i will change it everything to integeres and i will do ip2long($user_ip) in the db query. Also I will apply Gordon answer - selecting just 1 row not count *. Thanks all guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use aggregation.  Instead, check whether the following returns any rows:

```
 SELECT 1
 FROM ip_ranges
 WHERE %s", $user_ip, " BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end
 LIMIT 1;
```

The `LIMIT 1` says to stop at the first match, so it is faster.

For this query, you want an index on `ip_ranges(ip_start, ip_end)`.

This still has a performance problem when there is no match.  The entire index after the ip being tested has to be scanned.  I think the following should be an improvement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT i.start, ip_end
      FROM ip_ranges i
      WHERE %s", $user_ip, " >= ip_start
      ORDER BY ip_start
      LIMIT 1
     ) i
WHERE $user_ip <= ip_end;
```

The inner subquery should use the index but pull back the first match.  The outer query should should then check the end of the range.  Here the `count(*)` is okay, because there is only one row.

Comment: Thanks, this should help a lot.